# CSG (THREE.js) » Import local csg.js into another JS-File?

Tags: javascript, import, three.js, csg

I want to work with `THREE.js` and especially with CSG, so that I can subtract two obj models from each other using boolean operations.
For this purpose I import the respective local files in a central JavaScript file, so that I can work with them in it.

With `THREE.js`, `OBJLoader2`, etc. I have solved it that way:

```
import * as THREE from './three.module.js';

import {OBJLoader2} from './OBJLoader2.js';

import {MTLLoader} from './MTLLoader.js';
```

Then I can access the corresponding elements.
(e.g. `const objLoader = new OBJLoader2();`)
So I am currently able to import obj models and visualize them in a canvas element.

Unfortunately I can't do this for the `CSG.js` file.

I found the file here: https://github.com/evanw/csg.js/blob/master/csg.js.

How do I import the local `CSG.js` file into my central JavaScript file?

```
import * as CSGfrom './CSG.js';

import {CSG} from './CSG.js';
```

Both imports unfortunately do not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use my csg library :) Its more robust than the existing csg library.

https://github.com/manthrax/THREE-CSGMesh

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. How can I convert an Object3D into a mesh?

Comment: function convert2BSP (object)
{
  var BSP;
  object.traverse( function ( child )
  {
    //console.dir(child);
    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
    {
      //console.dir(child);
      BSP = child.clone();
      BSP = CSG.fromMesh(BSP);
    }
  });
  return BSP;
} » I get the Mesh of the Object3D, but how can I Subtract?

Comment: Thank your very much, it works with your library :)